# Is the $0\times 0$ matrix (zero-times-zero matrix) a well-defined concept?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is the $0\times 0$ matrix a well-defined concept, and if yes, what can be said about it?

Intuitively it should be a well-defined concept, since we have the zero vector space, and every linear mapping between vector spaces (such as the zero mapping from the zero vector space to itself) can be represented by a matrix.

The determinant of a $0\times 0$ matrix should be $1$, intuitively, just as the zero-dimensional volume of a point is $1$.

If the $0\times 0$ matrix is a bad concept or ill-defined concept, can you explain where to find the catch?

Comment: It is welldefined, but its determinant is $1$. Keep in mind that there is exactly one permutation of the empty set, and that the empty product is $1$.

Comment: You can even create it in Matlab, see eg https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/empty-matrices-scalars-and-vectors.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com and also ftp://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/Approx/empty.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, one could say even more about the $0$ x $0$ matrix: Yes, it operates on the zero vector space (which contains only one single element = $0$). So, it maps $0$ to $0$ since there is no other possible image. Hence, it must be the identity mapping on the zero space, and therefore, it is its own inverse.

Comment: But the zero vector space is not empty, and vector spaces are defined over fields, the only linear operator over the zero space is the identity represented by the matrix $(\ 1\ )$, isn't it? I'm confused, does the $0 \times 0$ matrix represents the empty function?

Comment: This is a well-known trap! Observe that the zero space has dimension $0$, which implies that the matrices operating on this vector space cannot have dimension $1$ x $1$. They must have dimension $0$ x $0$. However, it is not the empty function, it represents the identity operation on the zero space.

Comment: Addendum to my last comment: You must distinguish between a one-dimensional vector $[0]$ and the element $0$ of the zero vector space with dimension $0$. Does this help to reduce the confusion?

Comment: On the other hand, adding the empty matrix to itself gives again the empty matrix, proving that the empty matrix is the zero element of the ring of empty matrices.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much bernhard and celtschk.

Comment: Just for completeness: The empty matrix $E_0$ is the neutral element for both addition and multiplication. So it is the single element of the so-called zero ring if we want to consider {$E_0$} as a matrix ring. This makes sense since for each dimension $n$ the $n$x$n$-matrices build a ring, so why not for $n=0$ ?

Comment: What is its logarithm? As it is not a zero divisor, it should have a well defined logarithm.

Comment: Also, what is its trace? Zero?

Comment: @Anixx, I would say that it has no eigenvectors, since there are no nonzero vectors $x$ that satisfy $\mathbf{0} x=\lambda x$.  Therefore it makes sense that its determinant is one (the empty product) and its trace is zero (the empy sum). It also vacuously satisfies the definition of a diagonal matrix, and since its diagonal is empty, we get the same results.

Comment: @Joe ok, this would also mean that its exponent and logarithm is itself.

Comment: @Anixx, yes, we get $\exp(X) = X$ for the $0\times 0$ matrix straight from the definition of matrix exponentiation as well.  As for the "modulus" of infinity, that is not a concept I am at all familiar with.

Comment: @Joe oh, found a typo, I deleted the comment. As to "modulus", I referred to this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403344/hypermodulus-and-what-mathematical-objects-have-it

Comment: @Joe it seems, we cannot isomorphically represent the $0\times0$ matrix with a matrix of higher rank... It could be interesting...

Comment: @Anixx, that is just far outside my area of ... I'll say experience, since I don't really have any area of expertise.

Answer (score 9):

Suppose $A$ is a linear operator on a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space $V$. Say $\dim_K V = n$. It induces a natural linear map $\wedge^n A$ on the exterior power $\wedge^n V$. The latter is a $1$-dimensional $K$-vector space, so that $\wedge^n A$ is multiplication by a scalar. This scalar is the determinant of $A$.
(This is the definition of determinant you'll find in Bourbaki.)

When $n = 0$, we have a natural identification $\wedge^0 V \cong K$, and the induced map $\wedge^0 A$ is (by construction) the identity map. I.e. multiplication by $1$. Thus $\det A = 1$.

Comment: This is the correct answer.