# What is the Minor of the element of $1\times 1$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Over the internet, some its $'1',$ and some say 'nothing' and no one say it confidently.
Which one is correct?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-minor-of-a-1x1-matrix

Comment: This is probably a matter of convention. Why do you ask the question? One possible answer is "the $0 \times 0$ matrix" (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913141/is-the-0x0-matrix-zero-times-zero-matrix-a-well-defined-concept ).

Comment: @Travis Answer to "Why do you ask the question?" is the curiosity and in one books it's written that 'Minor of element of determinant of order n is determinant of order n-1, **n=>2**'.

Comment: @Travis Thanks for the link, you should post it as an answer.