# Matrix of the linear transformation $T : \{0\} \to \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am kindly asking for someone to clarify the following doubt.

Is there a matrix for a linear transformation $T : \{0\} \to \{0\}$? I can generalize this question to the following.

> Is there a matrix for a linear transformation mapping the trivial vector space to another vector space (or vice-versa)?

I believe there isn't since a matrix (as Axler defines it in the 3rd edition of *Linear Algebra Done Right*) is defined for some positive integers $m$ and $n.$ Specifically, the integer $m$ specifies the dimension of the vector space in the domain, and the integer $n$ specifies the dimension of the codomain. As the dimension of the trivial vector space is $0,$ I believe there is no matrix for such linear transformation.

Thank you.

Comment: It's a zero-by-zero matrix! I might write it as $()$.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913141/is-the-0-times-0-matrix-zero-times-zero-matrix-a-well-defined-concept?r=SearchResults

Comment: Thank you both. And thanks Joe, i missed that post.

Comment: If $T : \{0 \in \mathbb{R}^m \} \to \{0 \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$ then any $n\times m$-matrix works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the comment above that it would be an empty matrix of some kind (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Empty_matrices), however since the dimension of the codomain might be non-zero, it would more generally be a $n \times 0$ matrix. Either way there are no elements in it, so this point is mostly technical.

The reason this feels awkward is that there is exactly one function from the vector space of dimension 0 to any other vector space (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#empty_function). So whereas typically matrixes "encode information" about a linear transformation, in this case, there is no information to encode. If I say "I have a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^0$ to $\mathbb{R}^5$" and you say "which one?", the *only* thing I can say in response is "You know, THE transformation".